# how to delete a shape after drawing it in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I am making a game in pygame. I use a "laser" as the projectile the player shoots. I currently use a system that when a certain condition is true, I change the color of the laser to red. however, this does not work with collidirect. Collidirect immediately "activates" when the "laser" is colliding with an entity.
The laser is drawn at the last line of my code.

Here is the code:

```
import pygame
import sys
# Creating a loop to keep program running
    while True:
       
        # --- Event Processing and controls
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    spaceship_x_change = 10
                elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    spaceship_x_change = -10
                elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    red = (255, 0, 0)
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                red = (0, 0, 0)
                spaceship_x_change = 0

        spaceship_x += spaceship_x_change

        # Preventing the ship from going off the screen
        if spaceship_x > display_width - 140:
            spaceship_x -= 10
        if spaceship_x < 1:
            spaceship_x += 10

        pygame.draw.rect(game_display, red, [spaceship_x + 69, 70, 4, 310])
```

Comment: I believe the way to do it is just not to draw it. Your game loop is essentially redrawing what you put in there each frame, to delete something is an equivalent of not drawing it anymore. 

There are numerous ways to do that, the code you've included doesn't really show how you handle the rest of the game so perhaps putting the draw laser part of the loop into a conditional (if-else) block would be an easy way to remove it when you don't want to draw it.

Comment: @grizzle oh sorry i should have added more code. people said I should have only put the amount of code needed

Comment: I really don't understand the question. `I change the color of the laser to red. however, this does not work with collidirect.` I see no `colliderect` in your code; also, which role does the color play here? ` Collidirect immediately "activates" when the "laser" is colliding with an entity.` What's the meaing of `activates` here?

Comment: @sloth the statement becomes true. i use a system where the color changes to red when a certain condition is true, however, even when the color isn't red, the collision is detected between entities, and my main point is, how to remove the shape after drawing it.

Comment: `my main point is, how to remove the shape after drawing it` As Grizzle more or less said, if you want to stop to do something, you just stop doing it. If you don't want to check the collision between two rectangles, just don't it? If you don't want to draw something, just don't draw it. Maybe you could try to better describe what your goal is, what you tried to do and what you expect to happen.

Comment: @snoopstick As far as I can see, they don't use classes and objects. The great advantage of an object is that it can have any number of properties (attributes). If the behavior of an object needs to change, it is sufficient to change a property. Organize your objects in groups (or lists). When you "delete" something, simply remove it from the group (or list).

Comment: @rabbid76 ah THANKS! much more clearer to me now!

Answer (score 0):

This is just a theoretical example, since the snippet doesn't work on it's own I will just show you an example of how you might implement removing an object.

So if you wanted to remove the spaceship when it reached the edge of the screen, you would do something along these lines.

```
import pygame
import sys
# Creating a loop to keep program running

draw_spaceship = True

    while True:
       
        # --- Event Processing and controls
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    spaceship_x_change = 10
                elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    spaceship_x_change = -10
                elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    red = (255, 0, 0)
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                red = (0, 0, 0)
                spaceship_x_change = 0

        spaceship_x += spaceship_x_change

        # Preventing the ship from going off the screen
        if spaceship_x > display_width - 140:
            draw_spaceship = False
        elif spaceship_x < 1:
            draw_spaceship = False
        else:
            # spaceship is within the screen bounds
            draw_spaceship = True

        if draw_spaceship:
            # this doesnt actually draw the spaceship,
            # but you would put the equivalent code here that did that.
            pygame.draw.rect(game_display, red, [spaceship_x + 69, 70, 4, 310])
```

So you need a flag or some condition that you want to check for that will dictate if you draw an object or not.